# what does 754 mean in IEEE 754 floating point number?

Tags: ieee-754, ieee

There are lots of IEEE standard.and almost all languages guarantee to implement IEEE 754 binary floating-point numbers.

Comment: It's just a standard number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just the running number, like IRC has RFC1459